# PHP gmdate find out if it's been a year

Tags: php

I was just wondering how you would be able to find out if something is x amount old. My problem is that I want to find out if this item is a year old, but I'm using unix timestamp. I convert it using gmdate so that it's read-able. Next, I try to compare it to 3600, but it's not working.

Here's my code below.

```
$unix_timestamp = 1373058307;
$gmdate = gmdate("m/d/Y", $unix_timestamp);
echo $gmdate;

if($gmdate >= 3600) {
    echo "<br>1 year already";
} else {
    echo "<br>Hasn't been a year yet";
}
```

The echo $gmdate is just to test what date it's on. And I get 07/05/2013 which is the correct date I'm looking for. Now since it's 2015, I want to compare it so that it says 1 year already. I know I should check to see if it's 2 years, but this particular thing I'm doing only needs to be checked if it's a year or more.

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: `$gmdate` is in "m/d/Y" format. Why do you think you can compare it to an integer? Are you just trying to see if a timestamp is more than a year old?

Comment: @JohnConde I actually went back and re-think what I was doing and I decided to remove the m/d/ so that it only leaves the year. I'm trying to compare it to the current time using the same unix timestamp. Yes, I'm trying to find out if a timestamp is more than a year old. I've Googled it, but I believe I didn't phrase it right.

Comment: `if (time() - $unix_timestamp > 31557600) { /*greater than one year*/}`. Just one of many ways to do this.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks, is this one right as well? `$gmdate = gmdate("Y", $unix_timestamp); $gmdate_current_time = gmdate("Y", time()); if($gmdate_current_time >= $gmdate) { echo "1 year already"; }`

Comment: Yes, but that's a long winded way to do it. And not very efficient.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks. I just realized that it doesn't check for the year thing. It only checked if the date was greater. I'll use your example. Thanks a lot.